# What does 'this' refer to when the function that uses it is called as `new myFunction("Hello")`

Tags: javascript, this

```
function myFunction(message)
{
this.message = message;
return this.message;
}

document.body.innerHTML = new myFunction("Hello");
```

I learnt that "in JavaScript `this` always refers to the 'owner' of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of." [reference](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)

In this example it would seem that the this in myFunction should refer to the owner of the myFunction then, the window. It seems like it's referring to the myFunction though. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `new` operator, you create a new instance of an object defined in the [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_Constructor_Function) and `this` refers to the new object.

Old answer before the question was completely changed by the addition of the new keyword:

<del>Since `myFunction` is not being called with the `new` keyword, or in the explicit context of another object, it is effectively: `document.body.innerHTML = window.myFunction("Hello");`</del>

<del>So `this` is the `window` object.</del>

<del>You can confirm this by editing the function to `console.log` whatever `this` is and then looking in Firebug.</del>

Comment: Oh, wait, it was meant to be `new myFunction("hello")`

Answer (score 0):

If you call `new myFunction("hello")`, then `this` refers to a new "empty" object (it does not refer to the function!) that inherits from the functions prototype property (`myFunction.prototype`).

Such a function is also called constructor function and it is convention to start the name with a capital letter.